# How to open laravel website in VMWARE from local PC?

Tags: php, laravel, redhat, vmware

I have a laravel apps that i installed on VMWARE Redhat and using SQL Server on my local pc. I can open the website in VMWARE  and it can connect to my local Sqlserver. I also can open my local website from VMWARE browser.

But how to open my laravel website on VMWARE from local pc?

in /etc/hosts, i add this line

```
192.168.0.154 laravel.example.com
```

and here is my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.154
    ServerAlias laravel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/public
    Redirect permanent / https://192.168.0.154
   <Directory /var/www/xxx/public>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName 192.168.0.154
    ServerAlias laravel.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@laravel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/laravel.example.com-selfsigned.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/laravel.example.com-selfsigned.key"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;  includeSubDomains"
```

i already run php artisans serve using port 80/8080/433, and open the website in local pc with url **http://laravel.example.com:port/**  and still get error

```
php artisan serve --host laravel.example.com --port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some log on your web server when you try to connect on it ? If so, you will get more information that might help you to solve your problem.

Did you add `192.168.0.154 laravel.example.com` on your local PC too ? It's necessary.

You can check if the firewall on your VM doesn't block your connection.